# Web.py Period after variable in template

Tags: python, web.py

I have a template where I'm passing `string1` and `string2` to it.

I then want to display the passed variables like `string1string2.zip` but the problem is it gets read as if I want to get the zip attribute from string2 instead of displaying it as separate text.

The error created is
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'zip'`

Any way around this?

Not sure why this was downvoted..

Comment: Show the template. Identify the template language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(string1)$(string2).zip
```